# Showing that the Fourier transform of $-ixf(x)$ is equal to $ c'(w)$ without knowledge of real analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis

We are supposed to be able to show that the Fourier transform of  $-ixf(x)$ is equal to $c'(w)$ without using knowledge of real analysis.

Trying to transform the above yields the following integral:
$\frac{-i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) e^{-i w x} dx$

I've never seen such an integral before, and assuming f(x) has 1 or more x's, and not knowing whether its component(s) can be merged with something else in the integral we can't use integration by parts as I know it with 2 components. how would one go on solving this type of problems?

**Update:**
$c$ is the fourier transform of $f$

Comment: What is $c$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Sorry for that,
c(w) is the Fourier transform of f(x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you (all computations here are strictly formal - this is not intended to be rigorous) differentiate $$c(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-iwx}\, dx$$ you get $$c'(w) = \frac{-i}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) e^{-i w x} \, dx.$$ Compare this to the formula you provided.

Comment: I think your convention is different: $c$ itself will have a minus sign in the exponent, which is where there is a discrepancy of $-1$ between the two formulae.

Comment: Yeah, I was guessing about $c$ based on the formula provided. I will change it.

Comment: I believe the lack of dx at the end of the first integral is unintentional?
Ok so we are basically partially differentiating c w.r.t. omega $(w)$, and the function $f(x)$ appears to not be a function of $w$.
@Ian: Thx Ian that is correct, the minus sign should be there.